# SQL Server different types of variables, $ and @

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I am unsure of the difference between types of variables when using SSMS and SQL server.

```
:SETVAR A 7
DECLARE  @B INT
SET @B = 11;
SELECT ($(A) * @B) AS PRODUCT
```

1. When should I be using SET and when SETVAR?
2. When should I be using '@' and when '$'?
3. When are parentheses required e.g. $(A) above and when not?

Are these all part of the query or is there a text substitution that occurs before the query runs, and if so is that due to use of the dollar sign or always happening?

In short, what's going on?

I am aware I can do this ...

```
sqlcmd.exe -v A=7
```

or something like it, in place of

```
:SETVAR A 7
```

[image: Screen Capture of SQL variable use]

Comment: Seems you need to read up on SQLCMD Mode. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2311/using-the-ssms-query-editor-in-sqlcmd-mode/

Comment: The SQLCMD documentation that I've seen seems to refer to variables which can be changed using SETVAR. I have not seen any comparison there to an alternative syntax for variables which use DECLARE and SET, and balancing the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: The alternate you speak of is standard t-sql.

Comment: SQLCMD variables are basically just text macros. I don't believe you can do any kind of math with them. And you're limited to using them from SQLCMD (mode).

Comment: I've got it now. The text macro description was useful. I experimented a little and it seems the text is parsed twice to create the SQL from the SETVAR and $variables. The first pass collecting variable values and the second pass performing substitution. The SET and @variables are then part of the resulting SQL. This was instructive. :SETVAR Z 11
SELECT $(Z) AS [RedefinedLater]
:SETVAR Z 13